# Import swagger to APImanagement through powershell script not working in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, swagger, azure-api-management

I am trying to deploy web application with Rest api and after that add the api definition (swagger.json) to API management service. This should be done in powershell step via `Import-AzApiManagementApi` cmdlet. It works locally with the same arguments, but not in the pipeline. Is there some bug that I don't know about, or some hidden dependency?

```bsh
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionID $subscriptionId;
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServiceName $serviceName;
Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId $apiId -SpecificationFormat "OpenApiJson" -SpecificationPath $swaggerPath -ServiceUrl "https://$webAppHostName" -Path $apiPath
```

I've tried without specifying the `apiId` or `ServiceUrl` but no luck. I found some hint to also set it afterwards (fixes some bug), but this also does not work.

```bsh
Set-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId $apiId -Name $ApiName -Path $ApiPath -Protocols @("https") -ServiceUrl $ServiceUrl
```

but also no luck. Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: 'Doesn't work normally in the pipeline',what is the specific situation? Are there any errors or warnings?You can try importing api with private agent.In addition, here are the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/scripts/powershell-import-api-and-add-to-product) and [blog](https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2017/07/setting-continuous-delivery-azure-api-management-vsts/) you can refer to .

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Comment: Doesn't work normally: It doesn't produce any errors, just silently does not import the swagger. 
Some colleagues found existing plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim, so we are using that for the time being.

Comment: Glad to hear you found an alternative. You can try import of API using private agent to see if this work.In addition, do you use Azure PowerShell task?

Comment: You can consider to convert your workaround into an answer, this would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.